# I need to find vulnerable openssl so i can make tests on it

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

I need to find some vulnerable openssl version, so i can make test on it.
Untill now i can not find anything related vulnerable openssl version.

Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 1):

Your hopefully shouldn't find anywhere hosting the binaries in case someone uses them by accident

Your best bet is to compile your own

Depending which exploit your are looking for will depend on the version you need to check out and compile

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/4817504d069b4c5082161b02a22116ad75f822b1
Is the commit which introduced heartbleed for example